# Reminders.app grocery list auto-categorization is not working (MacOS Sonoma)

Tags: macos, reminders, sonoma

The reminders app in Sonoma is supposed to have this new feature where it auto sorts your [grocery list](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/reminders/remn175e6897/7.0/mac/14.0).

I can't get it to work though, the items I add to the list just stay as a list (no auto-categorization)

I've

- Ensured I'm signed into iCloud
- Enabled Reminders in the iCloud settings
- Set the groceries list to the "Shopping" type when doing "Show list info"

The only thing I can see is this error in `Console.app` that seems suspect

```
RDGroceryOperationCategorizeRemindersInList: Failed to predict categories of reminder titles {listObjectID: ~<x-apple-reminderkit://REMCDList/8EC3F3ED-7BA0-44E1-88BA-B9C9E4022A9D>, reminderIDs: [<<REMObjectID_Codable: 0x128356ef0>>~<x-apple-reminderkit://REMCDReminder/EC436CA8-EF70-493A-9A90-C09AFF928C06>], 
groceryLocaleID: en_GB, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 
"The file “manifest.json” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." 
UserInfo={NSFilePath=/en_GB/manifest.json, NSUnderlyingError=0x11ef0d0b0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}}
```

My locale is set to `en_GB` so I'm guessing that's why that error is thrown, but is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you create a Standard list with grocery items, and then change the list type to Shopping afterwards? I haven't had any problem with it, (tbh I didn't know Reminders could now do it as I'm normally a pen and notebook shopper), but I did have an old list from a few years ago, and it correctly categorised it when I changed type from Standard to Shopping. Also `en_GB`

Comment: @AndyGriffiths doesn't fix the issue unfortuantely, same problem of nothing happening, and I can see that error in the log.

Comment: Do you have an iOS 17 device you could try it on, and see if it syncs? My iPhone is just off the end of the list for 17 unfortunately.. Was just about to link a similar question on Reddit for you, until I realised it was yours! Another thing... see if you can create a shopping category and see if it makes it behave. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/reminders/remnbb50db03/7.0/mac/14.0

Comment: I just tried it on iPad with iOS 17 and the auto categorizaton _does_ work there and I can see the categories sync to the mac. However if you add items on the mac app they just get added to the end of the list and no categorisation happens.

Comment: I've filed a bug report on Feedback Assistant, will see what happens.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. I am using en_GB as a language (and have been since I bought my Mac). Are you writing your shopping list in English?

Comment: 24 Hours later this started working and I no longer see the errors in Console.app.

Answer (score 2):

24 Hours later this started working and I no longer see the errors in Console.app.

I've reported the bug via Feedback Assistant anyway, but I guess this question can be closed?

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted solution to close the question